# How to use Jackson to parse XML files with streaming API

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm looking for a way to parse a large xml using kotlin.

My usual JSON parser is Jackson, and I know it can also be used to parse xml.

The source file is too large to be parsed using a DOM approach, and I must instead using the streaming API. I can find several example on how to use jackson streaming API with JSON, but nothing about XML.
Documentation https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml says

> Although module implements low-level (JsonFactory / JsonParser / JsonGenerator) abstractions, most usage is through data-binding level. This because a small number of work-arounds have been added at data-binding level, to work around XML peculiarities:

and this made my worried if a streaming approach of XML with this lib is even possibile and/or supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read a tree structure require process STARTING (e.g. `<element>` for *XML* or `{ / [` for *JSON*) that's way is not possible read the entire object while it is processed in a streaming way.

Let the root wrapper and a big list of cars (for brevity I use lombok annotations):

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JacksonXmlRootElement
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
static class CarBook {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private int version;
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "cars")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "car")
    private List<Car> cars;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
static class Car {
    private String model;
    private String plate;
}
```

then, you cannot get a `CarBook` object until all list (an may be other members) are fully readed.

The usual way then, is use a `XMLStreamReader` and check token by token what you get but you can use jackson to parse entire objects using the `XmlMapper` method:

```
/**
 * Method for reading a single XML value from given XML-specific input
 * source; useful for incremental data-binding, combining traversal using
 * basic Stax {@link XMLStreamReader} with data-binding by Jackson.
 * 
 * @since 2.4
 */
public <T> T readValue(XMLStreamReader r, Class<T> valueType) throws IOException {
    return readValue(r, _typeFactory.constructType(valueType));
}
```

as an example, let the big (1,2G) file:

```
<CarBook version="1"><cars>
<car><model>Alfa Romeo Spider</model><plate>27437</plate></car>
<car><model>Almera</model><plate>6429</plate></car>
<car><model>Audi 80 and 90</model><plate>4898</plate></car>
<car><model>Audi A3</model><plate>21259</plate></car>
<car><model>Audi A4</model><plate>21056</plate></car>
<car><model>Audi Coupé</model><plate>5623</plate></car>
<car><model>Austin Metro</model><plate>26446</plate></car>
<car><model>BMW 3 Series</model><plate>16338</plate></car>
<car><model>BMW 5 Series</model><plate>29859</plate></car>
...
```

the, you can read lazily with

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, XMLStreamException {
    XmlMapper xm = new XmlMapper();
    XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamReader xr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(/* 1,2G file */ "/home/josejuan/tmp/all.cars.xml"));

    // you must to read step by step
    while (xr.hasNext()) {
        xr.next();
        if (xr.getEventType() == START_ELEMENT) {
            System.out.println(xr.getLocalName());
            if ("car".equals(xr.getLocalName())) {
                Car car = xm.readValue(xr, Car.class);
                System.out.println(car);
                if ("21056".equals(car.getPlate()))
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("== End Of Process ==");
}
```

with output

```
CarBook
cars
car
WithLazyJackson.Car(model=Alfa Romeo Spider, plate=27437)
car
WithLazyJackson.Car(model=Almera, plate=6429)
car
WithLazyJackson.Car(model=Audi 80 and 90, plate=4898)
car
WithLazyJackson.Car(model=Audi A3, plate=21259)
car
WithLazyJackson.Car(model=Audi A4, plate=21056)
== End Of Process ==
```

reading only 5 cars out of 19.800.000

Comment: Thanks, your example will be helpful. I was looking into the wrong direction, doing everything with Jackson, but I see that `XMLInputFactory`  and the `XMLStreamReader`  are instead from the java sdk.

Comment: @Paparazzo _"but I see"_ yes, jackson is a parser but add a lot of helpers, it can parse `Car` instances from any source, `String`, `InputStream`, `Reader`, `byte []`, ... also contains a lot of helpers reading from `File`, `URL`, ... but also from the standard `XMLStreamReader`, as you can read in the commented `readValue` is provided mainly for lazy reading, luckily... :)